# In ASP.NET MVC3, will cshtml files be compiled? Liks JSP files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In Java EE, A Servlet container will transform JSP files to a Servlet class and compile that.

So, how does an ASP.NET server process .cshtml files?

Comment: Yes, it does compile the C# code and markup. Is there a specific reason you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, when the application in running, every request to a particular cshtml will compile it.
- No, when the application is being built. This behavior can be changed.